# How to route requests to a different servlet with WebFlux

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, soap, cxf, spring-webflux

I'm trying to migrate some legacy SOAP services from one application (Spring WebMVC, Boot, Tomcat) to other (Spring WebFlux, Boot, Netty). Those services are written using Apache CXF.

So in the original project, they used to work fine, and the following configuration was used:

```java
// imports

@Configuration
public class SoapWebServiceConfig {

    @Bean(name = "cxf")
    public SpringBus springBus() {
        var loggingFeature = new LoggingFeature();
        loggingFeature.addSensitiveProtocolHeaderNames(Set.of("Server", "Accept", "Date"));
        loggingFeature.setPrettyLogging(true);

        var springBus = new SpringBus();
        springBus.getFeatures().add(loggingFeature);
        return springBus;
    }

    @Bean
    public ActivateGateway activateGateway() {
        return new ActivateGatewayImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public Endpoint activateGatewayEndpoint(Bus bus, ActivateGateway activateGateway) {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, activateGateway);
        endpoint.publish("/activateGateway");
        return endpoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public CDACloudCommunicationPortType cdaCloudCommunicationPortType() {
        return new CloudCommunicationPortTypeImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public Endpoint cdaCloudCommunicationEndpoint(Bus bus, CDACloudCommunicationPortType cdaCloudCommunicationPortType) {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, cdaCloudCommunicationPortType);
        endpoint.publish("/controldata");
        return endpoint;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "cxfServletRegistration")
    public ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> cxfServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(
                new CXFServlet(), "/daas/activate/*", "/daas/controldata/*");
        servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

It created a servlet which worked fine alongside **DispatcherServlet** I suppose (I'm not the author of this code).

But when I moved this configuration to WebFlux, I cannot reach any of these endpoints, for example `GET /daas/activate/activateGateway?wsdl` gets mapped to some ResourceWebHandler, but not to CXFServlet.

Maybe I'm missing something and in WebFlux it's done differently.

**UPD: It seems like the reactive stack doesn't use servlets. Then the question is - what is used to implement SOAP services on top of reactive stack? Is there a possibility?**

Comment: You cannot run servlets on a reactive container afaik. So this won't work with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webflux doesn't rely on servlet. I don't actually think it is possible to connect CXF with webflux.

Comment: So there's no easy way.. Are there any options for migrating SOAP services to WebFlux ?

Comment: None (no library) that I know of but, in the end, it is an HTTP request/response so it is possible to implement yourself. Even though it is probably not so easy...

Comment: What about Spring WebServices module?

Comment: Last I checked it was still non-reactive implementation