# Running Spring WebServices alongside Spring WebFlux using Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, spring-webflux, spring-ws

Just for context: [How to route requests to a different servlet with WebFlux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72574280/how-to-route-requests-to-a-different-servlet-with-webflux)

Shortly, Netty web server is unable to run neither Apache CXF nor Spring WS because they work on top of Servlet API. But what about Tomcat? Tomcat supports newer Servlet API version
which in its turn supports reactive API (webflux).

**The question is: Is it possible to run WebFlux with Tomcat server and Spring WS for SOAP ?**

One servlet will be used for handling reactive operations, and the other for SOAP actions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run webflux on Tomcat using servlet (needed for CXF/Spring WS).

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-use-another-web-server

Comment: Sorry. I'll rephrase the answer...

Comment: Actually,... Why would you want to do that? Probably much easier to have 2 different apps

Comment: Why? Business requirement, I don't like it either. Why can't I use servlet? I tried creating a sample app which exposes simple endpoint through webflux (returns Mono) and also exposes soap endpoints through Spring WS. On top of Tomcat. Both seem to work. I can see from the logs that two servlets are being created. I just want to know maybe I misunderstood my result.

Comment: Just that Servlet is not reactive.

Comment: So it's still possible although there will be performance penalties?

Comment: I'm not sure on how webflux on tomcat servlet is implemented but I'm quite sure it would be "blocking" and not reactive. Meaning, a bit simplified, that HTTP calls will not release threads while waiting. I wouldn't say that you would get a performance penalty but will not get the full benefit of reactive (aka non-blocking)